# Отправка данных, введенных пользователем, в БД SQL Python

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reglearner'])
def reglearner(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите имя')
    first_name = message.text
    firstnameSQL = """INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) """  
    cursor.execute(firstnameSQL)
    db.commit()
```

Выводит ошибку

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s)' at line 
1
```

Comment: Вы забыли прописать собственно сами данные в execute

Comment: @andreymal ```cursor.execute(firstnameSQL)```

Comment: @andreymal извините, не сразу понял о чем речь, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reglearner'])
def reglearner(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите имя')
    first_name = message.text
    last_name = 'chto to'
    firstnameSQL = """INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s,%s) """ 
    val = (first_name,last_name) 
    cursor.execute(firstnameSQL,val)
    db.commit()
```

Спасибо @andreymal